# discord.py can't append to a json file

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to make a command that will add a user id, choice, and response to a json dictionary but I realized json.dump isn't the right function to use since it only replaces what's in the {} with the new values, How can I add the values to a new line in the {} instead of replacing it? I also get an error when I try to "append" the values but I'm not sure if it's because the user id is as an int, I tried converting the user id to a string but I get the same error

```
    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        with open("reports.json", "r") as f:
                data = json.load(f)
        if self.answer.value.lower() == "report" or self.answer.value.lower() == "suggestion":
            await interaction.response.send_message("Successfully submitted your report/suggestion.", ephemeral=True)
            print(f"{interaction.user} sent a {self.answer}: {self.answer2}")
            user = data["user"] = str(interaction.user.id)
            choice = data["choice"] = self.answer.value.lower()
            message = data["message"] = f"{self.answer2.value}\n"
            
            with open("reports.json", "w") as f:
                user.append(interaction.user.id)
                choice.append(self.answer.value.lower())
                message.append(self.answer2.value)
```

I get this error btw

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ui/modal.py", line 186, in _scheduled_task
    await self.on_submit(interaction)
  File "/home/container/main.py", line 312, in on_submit
    user.append(interaction.user.id)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: What does the JSON look like / what format do you expect? But `user = data["user"] = str(interaction.user.id)` is not what you want and the cause of the error. Try to modify `data`, then dump it back to the file.

Comment: I'm trying to make it line by line also how would I modify data?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a list of reports (JSON should be an object/dict at root, but can be tweaked to have the array/list at root):

```json
{
    "reports": [
        {
            "user": "user_a",
            "choice": "selected value",
            "message": "some message"
        },
        {
            "user": "user_b",
            "choice": "other value",
            "message": "another message"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Create a new entry for the list from your data, add it to the result list and finally save as JSON to the file.

```py
import json


async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    with open("reports.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    
    if self.answer.value.lower() == "report" or self.answer.value.lower() == "suggestion":
        await interaction.response.send_message("Successfully submitted your report/suggestion.", ephemeral=True)
        print(f"{interaction.user} sent a {self.answer}: {self.answer2}")
        
        new_result = {
            "user": str(interaction.user.id),
            "choice": self.answer.value.lower(),
            "message":  f"{self.answer2.value}\n"
        }
        data["results"].append(new_result)
        
        with open("reports.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ui/modal.py", line 186, in _scheduled_task
    await self.on_submit(interaction)
  File "/home/container/main.py", line 315, in on_submit
    data["results"].append(new_result)
KeyError: 'results'`

I get this error